# Android Custom ListView with ArrayList How do I open a second activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I have this Custom ListView with ArrayList and I am trying to Open second Activity Using 
the Icon Used is in the folder drawable

```
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}
```

but it force closes the app when I click on the ListItem
CbMain.java

```
package com.frostistudios.circuitbasicspro;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class CbMain extends Activity {

String[] listItems = {"Menu One","Menu Two","Menu Three"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cb_main);



    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); //listview in xml file
    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<CbMain.ListViewItem>();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            if(position == 0){
                //call to custom method for opening activity
                openItemOneActivity();
            }
            else if(position == 1){
                openItemTwoActivity();
            }
            else if(position == 2){
                openItemThreeActivity();
            }

        }
    });


    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_action_call;
        Title = listItems[0];
        SubTitle = "";


    }});
        items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_action_call;
        Title = listItems[1];
        SubTitle = "";


    }});
        items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_action_call;
        Title = listItems[2];
        SubTitle = "";


     }});

        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

  //custom methods to open another activity
public void openItemOneActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ItemOneActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} 
public void openItemTwoActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ItemTwoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} 
public void openItemThreeActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ItemThreeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} 

class ListViewItem {
    public int ThumbnailResource;
    public String Title;
    public String SubTitle;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;


}


}
```

CustomListViewAdapter.java
this is the custom list adapter file

```
package com.frostistudios.circuitbasicspro;

import java.util.List;
import com.frostistudios.circuitbasicspro.CbMain.ListViewItem;
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;  
import android.widget.ImageView;  
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{  

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListViewItem> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<ListViewItem> items) {  
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return items.size();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}

@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubtitle.setText(item.SubTitle);


    return vi;  
}
}
```

and this is the XML File that holds the ListView Design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: See the log cat, and tell us what it said when the force stop happens

Comment: [LogCat Image of Error](http://puu.sh/cygrJ/c2b154364a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking from your log cat, the error seems because the `theme` you used is not from the `compat`. Check your `manifest`, and make sure you use the `compat` theme.

Example (for ALL acitivities in your apps) :

```
<application
        //other code
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Or if you only use the action bar on particular activity :

```
<Activity
        //other code
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

TIPS :

Always pay attention to the `log cat`, especially the `caused by`. I know the problem from there.

Comment: Yes it worked and Thank you for your help but I want the Action Bar too, how do I get the action bar menu I believe that you must use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" theme in order to show action bar

Comment: Your activity should extends ActionBarActivity, instead of Activity

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you posted the error output. Are your other Activities declared in your manifest? You already have a context in the adapter, so you could set it there and try. I also think that View vi is unecessary, you can use convertView.

Comment: yes they are 

Basically I have this List View with string

    String[] listItems = {"Menu One","Menu Two","Menu Three"};

and using ListViewItems ArrayList I added thumbnails to the Item List and I want to get an intent where the user clicks on item one list view and another activity opens up